# Отображение правого бокового меню

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Делаю сайт, похожий на [Интернет магазин](https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/). Сохранил страницу на компьютер (Веб-сайт полностью). К сайту прилагаются 5 css файлов - `commons.bundle.css`, `subcategory.bundle.css`, `vendors.bundle.css`, `styles.css` и `template.css`. Скопировал код правого бокового меню, вставил его в файл и подключил вышеуказанные css файлы.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="commons.bundle.css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="subcategory.bundle.css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors.bundle.css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" media="all">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="template.css" media="all">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="helper" data-compatibility_filters="[]">
    <ul class="switcher type1 radio_style text views_switcher">
      <li class="for_all selected"><span class="pseudo">Фильтры</span><span class="close"><span class="text">Очистить</span></span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="helper_view helper_view_short">
      <div class="loader-animation" id="filter-loader-animation"></div>
      <section class="section1" data-condition="or" data-iscandisable="" data-name="Показывать товар" data-count="435"><span class="h4"><span class=" selected  for_section1_controls">
                                Показывать товар
                            </span></span>
        <div class="filter_radio filter_controls section1_controls" data-default="1" data-name="available"><span class="filter_item default selected" data-value="1" data-totalin="435"><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?available=1&amp;status=55395790">
                                            В Наличии
                                            <span class="counter" style="">435</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item" data-value="2" data-totalin="0"><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?available=2&amp;status=55395790">
                                            Есть в Магазине
                                            <span class="counter" style="display: none;">0</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item" data-value="13" data-totalin="0"><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?available=13&amp;status=55395790">
                                            Курортный проспект
                                            <span class="counter" style="display: none;">0</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item" data-value="0" data-totalin="0"><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?available=0&amp;status=55395790">
                                            Любой
                                            <span class="counter" style="display: none;">0</span></a>
          </span>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="section2" data-condition="or" data-iscandisable="" data-name="Статус"><span class="h4"><span class=" selected  for_section2_controls">
                                Статус
                            </span></span>
        <div class="filter_radio filter_controls section2_controls" data-default="55395790" data-name="status"><span class="filter_item disabled" data-value="1840753929" data-totalin="0"><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?status=1840753929&amp;available=1">
                                            Хит
                                            <span class="counter" style="display: none;">0</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item" data-value="90876589" data-totalin="45"><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?status=90876589&amp;available=1">
                                            Новинка
                                            <span class="counter" style="">45</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item disabled" data-value="1330703878" data-totalin="0"><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?status=1330703878&amp;available=1">
                                            Распродажа
                                            <span class="counter" style="display: none;">0</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item" data-value="468661653" data-totalin="37"><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?status=468661653&amp;available=1">
                                            Акция
                                            <span class="counter" style="">37</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item disabled" data-value="3231170597" data-totalin="0"><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?status=3231170597&amp;available=1">
                                            Уценка
                                            <span class="counter" style="display: none;">0</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item" data-value="884577030" data-totalin="43"><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?status=884577030&amp;available=1">
                                            Рассрочка
                                            <span class="counter" style="">43</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item default selected" data-value="55395790" data-totalin="0"><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?status=55395790&amp;available=1">
                                            Любой
                                            <span class="counter" style="display: none;">0</span></a>
          </span>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="section3" data-iscandisable="" data-name="Цена"><span class="h4"><span class=" selected  for_section3_controls">
                                Цена
                            </span></span>
        <div class="filter_controls section3_controls">
          <div class="slider short" data-params="{&quot;range&quot;:true,&quot;min&quot;:21990, &quot;max&quot;:379990, &quot;step&quot;: 1, &quot;values&quot;: [21990, 379990]}">
            <div class="slider_content rangeFilter" data-name="price"><input type="text" class="min min-input_js" value="21990" name="price_min">
              <div class="inner ui-slider ui-corner-all ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content">
                <div class="ui-slider-range ui-corner-all ui-widget-header" style="left: 0%; width: 100%;"></div><span tabindex="0" class="ui-slider-handle ui-corner-all ui-state-default" style="left: 0%;"></span><span tabindex="0" class="ui-slider-handle ui-corner-all ui-state-default" style="left: 100%;"></span></div><input type="text" class="max max-input_js"
                value="379990" name="price_max"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="section4" data-condition="or" data-iscandisable="" data-name="Бренд"><span class="h4"><span class=" selected  for_section4_controls">Бренд</span></span>
        <div class="filter_check filter_controls section4_controls"><span class="filter_item" data-name="8714_821ACER" id="filter-item-id-8714_821ACER" data-remove="0" data-totalin="80" data-exclusive="0" data-is-brand="1" data-filter-name="ACER"><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=8714_821ACER"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          ACER
          <span class="counter" style="">80</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item" data-name="8714_821APPLE" id="filter-item-id-8714_821APPLE" data-remove="0" data-totalin="33" data-exclusive="0" data-is-brand="1" data-filter-name="APPLE"><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=8714_821APPLE"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          APPLE
          <span class="counter" style="">33</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item" data-name="8714_821ASUS" id="filter-item-id-8714_821ASUS" data-remove="0" data-totalin="75" data-exclusive="0" data-is-brand="1" data-filter-name="ASUS"><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=8714_821ASUS"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          ASUS
          <span class="counter" style="">75</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item" data-name="8714_821DELL" id="filter-item-id-8714_821DELL" data-remove="0" data-totalin="48" data-exclusive="0" data-is-brand="1" data-filter-name="DELL"><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=8714_821DELL"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          DELL
          <span class="counter" style="">48</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item" data-name="8714_821HP" id="filter-item-id-8714_821HP" data-remove="0" data-totalin="78" data-exclusive="0" data-is-brand="1" data-filter-name="HP"><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=8714_821HP"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          HP
          <span class="counter" style="">78</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item" data-name="8714_821IRBIS" id="filter-item-id-8714_821IRBIS" data-remove="0" data-totalin="1" data-exclusive="0" data-is-brand="1" data-filter-name="IRBIS"><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=8714_821IRBIS"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          IRBIS
          <span class="counter" style="">1</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item filter_item_exclusive" data-name="8714_821IRU" id="filter-item-id-8714_821IRU" data-remove="0" data-totalin="28" data-exclusive="1" data-is-brand="1" data-filter-name="IRU"><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=8714_821IRU"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          IRU
          <span class="counter" style="">28</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item" data-name="8714_821LENOVO" id="filter-item-id-8714_821LENOVO" data-remove="0" data-totalin="77" data-exclusive="0" data-is-brand="1" data-filter-name="LENOVO"><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=8714_821LENOVO"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          LENOVO
          <span class="counter" style="">77</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item" data-name="8714_821MSI" id="filter-item-id-8714_821MSI" data-remove="0" data-totalin="15" data-exclusive="0" data-is-brand="1" data-filter-name="MSI"><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=8714_821MSI"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          MSI
          <span class="counter" style="">15</span></a>
          </span>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="helper_view helper_view_full">
      <section class="section5" data-condition="or" data-iscandisable="" data-name="Тип"><span class="h4"><span class=" selected  for_section5_controls">Тип</span></span>
        <div class="filter_check filter_controls section5_controls"><span class="filter_item" data-name="8638_821monoblok" id="filter-item-id-8638_821monoblok" data-filterid="8638_821monoblok" data-remove="0" data-totalin="435"><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="8638_821monoblok" style=""><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=8638_821monoblok"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          Моноблок
          <span class="counter">435</span></a>
          </span>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="section6" data-condition="or" data-iscandisable="" data-name="Диагональ экрана"><span class="h4"><span class=" selected  for_section6_controls">Диагональ экрана</span></span>
        <div class="filter_check filter_controls section6_controls"><span class="filter_item" data-name="8673_821" id="filter-item-id-8673_821" data-filterid="8673_821" data-remove="0" data-totalin="12"><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="8673_821" style=""><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=8673_821"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          меньше 18"
          <span class="counter">12</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item" data-name="8675_821" id="filter-item-id-8675_821" data-filterid="8675_821" data-remove="0" data-totalin="2"><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="8675_821" style=""><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=8675_821"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          от 19" до 20"
          <span class="counter">2</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item" data-name="8676_821" id="filter-item-id-8676_821" data-filterid="8676_821" data-remove="0" data-totalin="3"><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="8676_821" style=""><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=8676_821"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          от 20" до 21"
          <span class="counter">3</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item" data-name="8677_821" id="filter-item-id-8677_821" data-filterid="8677_821" data-remove="0" data-totalin="146"><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="8677_821" style=""><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=8677_821"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          от 21" до 22"
          <span class="counter">146</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item" data-name="8679_821" id="filter-item-id-8679_821" data-filterid="8679_821" data-remove="0" data-totalin="205"><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="8679_821" style=""><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=8679_821"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          от 23" до 24"
          <span class="counter">205</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item" data-name="8680_821" id="filter-item-id-8680_821" data-filterid="8680_821" data-remove="0" data-totalin="2"><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="8680_821" style=""><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=8680_821"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          от 24" до 25"
          <span class="counter">2</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item" data-name="8681_821" id="filter-item-id-8681_821" data-filterid="8681_821" data-remove="0" data-totalin="65"><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="8681_821" style=""><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=8681_821"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          от 25" и больше
          <span class="counter">65</span></a>
          </span>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="section7" data-condition="or" data-iscandisable="" data-name="Разрешение экрана"><span class="h4"><span class=" selected  for_section7_controls">Разрешение экрана</span></span>
        <div class="filter_check filter_controls section7_controls"><span class="filter_item disabled filter_item_faded" data-name="10775_8211080" id="filter-item-id-10775_8211080" data-filterid="10775_8211080" data-remove="1" data-totalin="0" style="display: none;"><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="10775_8211080" style=""><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=10775_8211080"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          1080
          <span class="counter" style="display: none;">0</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item" data-name="10775_8211366d1khd1768" id="filter-item-id-10775_8211366d1khd1768" data-filterid="10775_8211366d1khd1768" data-remove="0" data-totalin="12"><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="10775_8211366d1khd1768" style=""><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=10775_8211366d1khd1768"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          1366 х 768
          <span class="counter">12</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item" data-name="10775_8211440d1khd1900" id="filter-item-id-10775_8211440d1khd1900" data-filterid="10775_8211440d1khd1900" data-remove="0" data-totalin="2"><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="10775_8211440d1khd1900" style=""><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=10775_8211440d1khd1900"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          1440 х 900
          <span class="counter">2</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item" data-name="10775_8211920d1khd11080" id="filter-item-id-10775_8211920d1khd11080" data-filterid="10775_8211920d1khd11080" data-remove="0" data-totalin="386"><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="10775_8211920d1khd11080" style=""><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=10775_8211920d1khd11080"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          1920 х 1080
          <span class="counter">386</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item" data-name="10775_8213840d1khd12160" id="filter-item-id-10775_8213840d1khd12160" data-filterid="10775_8213840d1khd12160" data-remove="0" data-totalin="3"><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="10775_8213840d1khd12160" style=""><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=10775_8213840d1khd12160"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          3840 х 2160
          <span class="counter">3</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item" data-name="10775_8214096d1khd12304" id="filter-item-id-10775_8214096d1khd12304" data-filterid="10775_8214096d1khd12304" data-remove="0" data-totalin="15"><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="10775_8214096d1khd12304" style=""><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=10775_8214096d1khd12304"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          4096 х 2304
          <span class="counter">15</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item" data-name="10775_8215120d1khd12880" id="filter-item-id-10775_8215120d1khd12880" data-filterid="10775_8215120d1khd12880" data-remove="0" data-totalin="15"><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="10775_8215120d1khd12880" style=""><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=10775_8215120d1khd12880"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          5120 х 2880
          <span class="counter">15</span></a>
          </span>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="section8" data-condition="or" data-iscandisable="" data-name="Тип матрицы"><span class="h4"><span class=" selected  for_section8_controls">Тип матрицы</span></span>
        <div class="filter_check filter_controls section8_controls"><span class="filter_item" data-name="10719_821IPS" id="filter-item-id-10719_821IPS" data-filterid="10719_821IPS" data-remove="0" data-totalin="219"><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="10719_821IPS" style=""><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=10719_821IPS"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          IPS
          <span class="counter">219</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item" data-name="10719_821TN" id="filter-item-id-10719_821TN" data-filterid="10719_821TN" data-remove="0" data-totalin="7"><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="10719_821TN" style=""><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=10719_821TN"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          TN
          <span class="counter">7</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item" data-name="10719_821WVA" id="filter-item-id-10719_821WVA" data-filterid="10719_821WVA" data-remove="0" data-totalin="2"><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="10719_821WVA" style=""><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=10719_821WVA"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          WVA
          <span class="counter">2</span></a>
          </span>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="section9" data-condition="and" data-iscandisable="" data-name="Особенности"><span class="h4"><span class=" selected  for_section9_controls">Особенности</span></span>
        <div class="filter_check filter_controls section9_controls"><span class="filter_item" data-name="8642_821" id="filter-item-id-8642_821" data-filterid="8642_821" data-remove="0" data-totalin="434"><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="8642_821" style=""><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=8642_821"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          Встроенный Wi-Fi
          <span class="counter">434</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item" data-name="8643_821" id="filter-item-id-8643_821" data-filterid="8643_821" data-remove="0" data-totalin="432"><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="8643_821" style=""><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=8643_821"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          Встроенный Bluetooth
          <span class="counter">432</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item" data-name="8647_821" id="filter-item-id-8647_821" data-filterid="8647_821" data-remove="0" data-totalin="391"><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="8647_821" style=""><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=8647_821"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          Клавиатура в комплекте
          <span class="counter">391</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item" data-name="8648_821" id="filter-item-id-8648_821" data-filterid="8648_821" data-remove="0" data-totalin="391"><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="8648_821" style=""><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=8648_821"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          Мышь в комплекте
          <span class="counter">391</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item" data-name="8646_821" id="filter-item-id-8646_821" data-filterid="8646_821" data-remove="0" data-totalin="381"><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="8646_821" style=""><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=8646_821"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          Встроенная Web-камера
          <span class="counter">381</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item" data-name="8641_821" id="filter-item-id-8641_821" data-filterid="8641_821" data-remove="0" data-totalin="36"><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="8641_821" style=""><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=8641_821"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          Сенсорный экран
          <span class="counter">36</span></a>
          </span><span class="filter_item" data-name="8644_821" id="filter-item-id-8644_821" data-filterid="8644_821" data-remove="0" data-totalin="25"><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="8644_821" style=""><a class="pseudo" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/monobloki/?&amp;f=8644_821"><span class="remove_filter">×</span>          Поддержка NFC
          <span class="counter">25</span></a>
          </span>
        </div>
      </section>




    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/noindex-->
```

Но в результате получил искаженное меню (отличающееся от того, что приведено на сайте). Результат верстки моего кода должен совпадать с версткой на сайте.
Вот список подключаемых файлов

[image: Подключаемые css файлы]

view-source:https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/kosmeticheskie-pribory/

Comment: Не очень ясно сформулирована проблема, собственно вопроса в вашем сообщении тоже не видно...

Answer (score 2):

Вы как минимум забыли еще несколько css файлов. Например стили от бокового меню хранятся в vendors.css

Comment: а можете привести весь список  подключаемых файлов, пожалуйста. И как вы его нашли? Где можно посмотреть его (я заходил на вкладку Ноутбуки и компьютеры)? Я заходил на старую версию сайта.

Comment: Если смотрите через хром, то Ctrl + U, на открывшейся странице Ctrl + F, и ищите .css

Comment: в вопросе я привел список подключаемых файлов. Какие файлы я забыл? (подскажите очень нужна помощь)

Comment: Что сделать расписал выше. Не хочется делать это за вас. Если не справляетесь с такой задачей, то заплатите специалисту, чтобы он это сделал за вас.

Comment: ну хотя бы ссылку на ту страницу, на которой вы обнаружили дополнительные стили, дайте пожалуйста.

Comment: дело в том, что на этой странице есть различные пункты меню, ведущие на подстраницы, список стилей на разных страницах может отличаться (например, на стартовой странице есть файл `home.bundle.js`, которого нет на дочерних страницах)

Comment: я привел скриншот со страницы view-source:https://www.citilink.ru/catalog/sistemnye-bloki/ . Там нету файла `vendors.css`. Подскажите хотя бы в каком разделе сайта искать недостающие css файлы.

Comment: А вы смотрите на старой версии сайта или на новой?

Comment: на старой версии сайта